# Converting grouped /nested data table to tabular form

Tags: excel, nested, powerquery

I have been trying to covert tables that I get in the grouped format as in the picture to tabular form to make it pivotable. I have tried to use power query but not sure how to do it. I am not sure where to start and I appreciate your guidance as to where to start or how to make it

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use powerquery, Assuming those are spaces, your best bet is probably to add some custom columns that check the number of leading spaces from column one to determine the level. For example,

```
= if Text.StartsWith([Column1], "     ") then Text.Trim([Column1]) else null
```

then do something similar but with different leading space counts into separate columns, and then fill down to populate a table

You could alternately try to split the column on, lets say, 3 spaces, depending on what the indentions are. (0/3/6/9)

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I will give it a go now. Much appreciated